# JQuery object to PHP via ajax to send a mail()

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, email

So i am trying to send an object from a jQuery function to a PHP script to send them via mail(), but my E-Mails are always empty, so i think i might not really understand how i should do it to make it properly work

Here is the jQuery function

```
            function sendForm() {

            $surname = $('#surname').val();
            $name = $('#name').val();
            $email = $('#email').val();
            $comment = $('#q4').val();

            $to = 'asd@efg.de'
            $subject = 'Contact Form'

            $datastring = {$surname,$name,$email,$comment,$to,$subject}

            $.ajax({
                url: 'send.php',
                type: 'post', 
                data: $datastring,
                success: function() { 
                    alert('email sent!');
                }
            });
            return false;
        }
```

and here the send.php

```
<?php
$to      = $_POST[$to];
$subject = $_POST[$subject];
$message = $_POST[$comment];
$headers = 'From: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" .
    'Reply-To: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" .
    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
?>
```

What am i missing? Thanks for the help!

edit: I checked the $datastring and it had all the values of the form i wanted. Saved as an object

Comment: please check the value of  $to, $subject, $message you are sending $to variable ?

Comment: When developing, it's useful to do some simple debugging of the values. For instance, add `var_dump($_POST)` in the php script - that will help to see what you're actually sending. (and in your ajax success function, you can use `console.log` to display the return value, or use your browser's network inspector tools)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to give the properties of your data object names, otherwise you will get errors:

```
$datastring = {
    surname : $surname,
    name    : $name,
    email   : $email,
    comment : $comment,
    to      : 'asd@efg.de',
    subject : 'Contact Form'
};
```

On PHP side you get the values by this names again:

```
$surname = $_POST["surname"];
$name    = $_POST["name"];
$email   = $_POST["email"];
$comment = $_POST["comment"];
$to      = $_POST["to"];
$subject = $_POST["subject"];
```

Answer (score 1):

The way you create the object makes every value `undefined`, as you don't have real keys and values, you need to do it like this instead

```
function sendForm() {
    $datastring = {
        'surname' : $('#surname').val(),
        'name'    : $('#name').val(),
        'email'   : $('#email').val(),
        'comment' : $('#q4').val(),
        'to'      : 'asd@efg.de',
        'subject' : 'Contact Form'
    }

    $.ajax({
        url     : 'send.php',
        type    : 'post',
        data    : $datastring,
        success : function() {
            alert('email sent!');
        }
    });
    return false;
}
```

To get the values in PHP, you'd use strings as keys

```
$_POST["subject"];
```

Answer (score 1):

Try changing

```
$datastring = {$surname,$name,$email,$comment,$to,$subject}
```

to

```
$datastring = {'username':$surname,'name':$name,'email':$email,'contact':$comment,'to':$to,'subject':$subject}
```

Then change

```
$to      = $_POST[$to];
```

to

```
$to      = $_POST['to'];
```

And similar in the rest of the php code.

Comment: And never trust user inputs! So filter your $_POST vars

Comment: Fair comment, but it's not clear what filters should be applied here. The idea seems to be to allow arbitrary e-mail to arbitrary addresses. If the `to` address should be hard-coded, hard-code it into the php not the javascript.